# Как передать параметры в Django при создании модели

Tags: django

Есть вызов класса StatusField c двумя аргументами
Один список выбора, второй значение выбора по умолчанию

```
status = StatusField(StatusChoices,StatusChoices.STATUS_ACTIVE)
```

Вот класс

```
class StatusField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 50
        kwargs['verbose_name'] = "Статус"
        kwargs['help_text'] = "Оперативный статус элемента."
        kwargs['blank'] = True
        kwargs['null'] = True
        kwargs['choices'] = ??? #SiteStatusChoices
        kwargs['default'] = ??? #SiteStatusChoices.STATUS_ACTIVE
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Надо как-то передать ссылку с self

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена.
Параметры можно передать при создать класса.